# Exchanging a Google's authorization code for an access token

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

Following the process of authenticating users using Google's OAuth2, I managed to get to the point where my redirect URL is loaded (in the browser) and now I've got a `code` to authenticate the user with.

The next step would be to exchange the code that I have with an `accessToken`. Doing this in PHP is like (as instructed [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#handlingresponse)):

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Can someone please tell me how to do the same in Java?

Comment: See a clear example here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/auth/web-server

Comment: @cricket_007 Does it actually depend on that? I mean it shouldn't if it does! And I don't think it does, the example code c0der mentioned does it for me and I believe it's server agnostic.